# Merge and sum hashes inside a Ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, merge, sum

I have an Ruby array that looks like this:

```
[{ :date => '2018-02-01', :capacity => 5, :used_capacity => 3 },
 { :date => '2018-02-01', :capacity => 10, :used_capacity => 3 },
 { :date => '2018-02-02', :capacity => 5, :used_capacity => 3 }]
```

And I need to the hashes if they have the same date and sum the capacity and used_capacity fields.

So it needs to become:

```
[{ :date => '2018-02-01', :capacity => 15, :used_capacity => 6 },
 { :date => '2018-02-02', :capacity => 5, :used_capacity => 3 }]
```

Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Thnx!

Comment: Did you even try searching? This exact question has been answered many times on SO

Comment: _Sidenote:_ it’s not 1998 anymore, don’t use a hash-rocket notation for hashes with symbolic keys.

Comment: I certainly did but all the examples I found didn't have multiple key/values that needed a sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input = [{ :date => '2018-02-01', :capacity => 5, :used_capacity => 3 },
         { :date => '2018-02-01', :capacity => 10, :used_capacity => 3 },
         { :date => '2018-02-02', :capacity => 5, :used_capacity => 3 }]

input.group_by { |h| h[:date] }.
      values.
      map do |a|
        a.reduce do |acc, h|
          acc.merge(h) { |k, v1, v2| k == :date ? v1 : v1 + v2 }
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [{ :date => '2018-02-01', :capacity => 5, :used_capacity => 3 },
 { :date => '2018-02-01', :capacity => 10, :used_capacity => 3 },
 { :date => '2018-02-02', :capacity => 5, :used_capacity => 3 }]

arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:date]=>g) do |_,oh,nh|
    oh.merge(nh) { |k,ov,nv| k==:date ? ov : ov+nv }
  end
end.values
  #=> [{:date=>"2018-02-01", :capacity=>15, :used_capacity=>6},
  #    {:date=>"2018-02-02", :capacity=>5, :used_capacity=>3}]
```

This uses the forms of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) and [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employ a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. `update`.